# Rails - Determining group membership after authenticating against an OpenLDAP server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization, openldap

I am maintaining a Rails app that uses Devise LDAP for authentication. I am migrating away from Active Directory towards OpenLDAP, which I have set up with the same structure. OpenLdap was installed using the `apt-get` packages `slapd` and `ldap-utils` on an install of Ubuntu Client 12.04 64 bit.

I can authenticate against OpenLdap, however when I call

```
Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_entry(email)["memberOf"]
```

I am returning an empty array. In rails console, I can see that the ldap entry returned has no "`memberOf`" entry.

When I query the ldap server from a terminal I receive the following output:

```
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -x -b "cn=people,dc=example,dc=local" memberOf 

...

# fred fred, people, example.local
dn: cn=fred fred,cn=people,dc=example,dc=local
memberOf: cn=Authorisers,ou=example,dc=example,dc=local
...
```

Is anybody aware of why `ldapsearch` might be returning different results to Devise?, and does anybody know how to get return the memberOf attribute?

Thanks in advance

The gems relating to ldap authentication are (output from Bundle)

```
Using devise (2.1.2) 
Using net-ldap (0.2.2) 
Using devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.6.1) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9)  
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using mail (2.4.4)  
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9)
```

Comment: Did you wireshark the request from ruby? Does it issue a different one?

Comment: thanks @Tass, I'll have a look when i'm back in. I should compare wireshark captures between ruby, MS Active Directory, openldap , and also between ldapsearch and MS Active Directory and openldap

Comment: Hi @Tass, yes there is a difference. a remote "ldapsearch" specifies a "memberOf" AttributeDescription in the "searchRequest" message. However, this is missing from the request from Ruby to the ActiveDirectory LDAP server, yet the memberOf details still get returned. I wonder if there is a way to attach this attribute to the Ruby request, or configure openldap to return it?

Comment: Could you give me the gems you're using? I could take a look into them.

Comment: @Tass,  I've added some of the important Gems in the question above, if you need, other than these the Gems are the ones you get with a basic Rails project. Thanks

Comment: neither 0.2.2 of net-ldap nor 0.3.1 mention 'memberOf' anywhere, but there's some metaprogramming involved, so the attributes may be exposed. My experience with ldap is rather limited, so setting up a whole env to think with this stuff is a bit over the limit. If you set me up an ldap env with rails included, I might pick it up.

Comment: I see in net-ldap you can control the attributes with which you request in ldap searches (http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html#method-i-search). I'm a ruby rails  and openldap newb myself - I watched this video to set up openldap (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM_UQVVVtoY). I might see if there is a way to get/configure devise to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

a) Did you try to use

Devise::LdapAdapter.get_groups(email)

b) Did you look at /config/ldap.yml

There are some configuration parameters in there (like required_groups, require_attribute, check_group_membership). May be it's just configured to ignore memberOf

You can take a look how all of them are used in [here](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/ldap_adapter.rb).

Comment: Thanks @Victor - i'll do a bit of experimenting with get_groups tomorrow. There's nothing excluding memberOf in the ldap.yml - maybe you need to explicitly request it. I read that you get an extra 24 hours after the bounty expires to award it!

Comment: Look at this list (it shows something regarding ldap.yml and memberOf - http://forum.lucidworks.com/lwe/quick-question-on-ldap-ldap-configyml

Comment: And here is another: https://github.com/ibe/s3u/blob/master/eligibilitycheck/config/ldap.yml.example

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - some useful avenues of research there!  - unfortunately none of them provided an instant solution (get_groups returned an empty array and I didn't have time to get to the bottom of all the options in ldap.yml. I see there is also a "in_ldap_group?" method that I will have a go with (i did +1 to ensure you got half of the bounty)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise ldap plugin use this

connection = Devise::LDAP::Connection.new({:login=>"user1"})
connection.in_group?('cn=grp1,--')

It returns true if user1 exists in grp1